# Access child views in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

**Background:**

I am trying to create a table view with around 4 types of different cell layout.

At first, I considered using static table view to solve the issue since the number of rows are somewhat fixed (nor more than 10)

But, after some thinking, I decided that I don't really want to be tied up to the `UITableViewController`. Thus, I tried to implement it with dynamic table view.

**Question:**

After I create 4 prototype cells, I found out that I'll need to access the child views in cell (to update their value). But the only possible ways I know seem to be:

```
1. Create a subclass for each prototype cell, and create `IBOutlet` to the child views

2. Assign `tag` for each child view for later access
```

But I don't really like these two methods...

The first one is too cumbersome, and the tag in the 2nd solution does't seem to be very sepcific (access the child view by just some magic number..)

**So, I would like to know:**

1. Is there any better practice for implementing this kind of
       tableview. (multiple cell prototypes, and fixed row numbers)
2. Is static table view a better way to do it? If yes, will there be
       any limitations when I am tied up to `UITableViewController`? 
   For example, if I need more complex UI, and decide to add more views on to it, will `UITableViewController` be less flexible than `UIViewController`

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cells are very similar but with different layouts they could share a common `UITableViewCell` subclass provided the class doesn't need to know the layout it is in just configure the available outlets.

If the code does need to be aware of the layout used then it is probably best to make them separate subclasses.

For Swift use `is` or `as?` to confirm the correct subclass for the cell (for Objective C it would be the `isKindOfClass` method).

Comment: Hi! if I just use UITableViewCell for all prototypes cells, how can I update the the value of UI controls in each cell?

Comment: I meant that you could make one subclass that is used for all of the prototypes. This makes sense if they all have similar elements just arranged differently. It would then have all the outlets that you need for all the prototypes although in some cases maybe some of them stay nil (Make your outlets proper optionals (`?`) not force unwrapped (`!`).

Comment: I think for now, your answer seems to be reasonable, and I accept it

Answer (score 0):

1.You do need to subclass the UITableViewCell if you want to access his IBOutlets. 
In order to distinguish between the cell just use isKindOfClass

2.It depends how different your cell are from one another. If they have slightly different structure you might want to consider lodging the elements in cellForRow. Try to take a look at the built in structure cause it might save you some subclassing. 
These structures have built in parameters such as: image,text etc.
Their structure is more strict though

Theses are the available types:

```
UITableViewCellStyleDefault,    // Simple cell with text label and optional image view (behavior of UITableViewCell in iPhoneOS 2.x)
UITableViewCellStyleValue1,     // Left aligned label on left and right aligned label on right with blue text (Used in Settings)
UITableViewCellStyleValue2,     // Right aligned label on left with blue text and left aligned label on right (Used in Phone/Contacts)
UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    // Left aligned label on top and left aligned label on bottom with gray text (Used in iPod).
```

I don't really understand why you want to use tags?

Comment: The reason I considered using tags is because I don't want to make subclasses for all prototype cells. Actually, I want to avoid using IBOutlets..